# Overlay 1 Xml on top of Another (superset)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, merge

1st all possible fields

```
  <HRMasterData>                  
      <MasterPersonDossier>           
        <MasterPerson>
          <PersonDetails>               
            <PersonID></PersonID>
            <PersonName>                        
              <GivenName></GivenName>
              <PreferredName></PreferredName>
              <MiddleName></MiddleName>
              <FamilyName></FamilyName>
              <FormerFamilyName></FormerFamilyName>
              <TitleAffixCode></TitleAffixCode>
              <PersonNameInitials></PersonNameInitials>
              <NewField></NewField>
            </PersonName>
            <EffectiveDateTime></EffectiveDateTime>
            <HomeCountry></HomeCountry>
            <NewField></NewField>
        </PersonDetails >
    </MasterPerson>
  </MasterPersonDossier>
</HRMasterData>
```

2nd Data, not always all fields present

```
    <HRMasterData>           
        <MasterPersonDossier>       
          <MasterPerson>
            <PersonDetails>                 
              <PersonID>abc</PersonID>
               <PersonName>             
                <GivenName>Smith</GivenName>
                <PreferredName>Jack </PreferredName>
                <MiddleName>John</MiddleName>
                <TitleAffixCode>Mr.</TitleAffixCode>
                <PersonNameInitials>w</PersonNameInitials>
              </PersonName>
              <EffectiveDateTime>2011-01-11</EffectiveDateTime>
              <HomeCountry>US</HomeCountry>
             </PersonDetails >
             </MasterPerson>
      </MasterPersonDossier>
    </HRMasterData>
```

I want to overlay the existing values of the second document onto the first doc (superset). I will then map an external system to the superset, Mapping fields the 2nd  doesn't have (i.e. Newfield). Then all the data gets pushed down for an update.

What is the best possible way to do this ?

I tried dataset merges but had issues. My fall back will be 2 loops checking for tag existence in 2nd and updating 1st xml.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are the names of the fields always the same, it is just some fields are missing? Also, do you have a XSD file that defines the schema, or just the template xml from the first example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes names will be the same. Order is a sequence. Just that some will be missing in second file. I don't have an xsd, the validation relies on business layer and db unfortunately.. Thanks !